# Put text on the same line with button

Tags: html, css, button, inline

I'm trying to put the text with button on right on the same level but for some reason it doesn't show up correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.lyrics {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.lyrics a {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.lyrics a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: #f0d0b5;
}

lyric-align {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
Song Title <div class="lyrics"><a href="#">Lyrics</a>
```

Comment: Well a div is a block element....

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I see in your code:

1. A div is a block element, it's going to take up the whole page horizontally where it is placed.
2. The button is there, you can see it if you hover over the space below the text Song Title. But you don't have a closing  tag for the first  tag.

Extra Credit

3. Your CSS for your class lyric-align is missing a dot in front of the class's identifier.

Answer (score -1):

Just write html like this:

```
<div class="lyrics">Song Title <a href="#">Lyrics</a></div>
```

And css like this:

```
.lyrics {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.lyrics a {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  
}

.lyrics a:hover {
  color: black;
  background: #f0d0b5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And because now you have one div, you can move him where you want. If you want to have a wonder size not across the entire page, but just around the text, use:

```
.lyrics{
  width: fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
}
```

## My recommended solution

I think the best solution would be to do it without DIV, leave only the "a" element there and style it like this. But I don't know what part of the page you didn't show.

### HTML

```
Song Title <a href="#" class="lyrics">Lyrics</a>
```

### CSS

```
.lyrics {
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.lyrics:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: #f0d0b5;
}
```

Comment: But I want to preserve the styling of the button. How do I achieve that?

Comment: So how do I preserve the styling of the button and be on the same line?

Comment: Your problem was that you put the text before the div, but the div as such stretches across the entire width of the page because it is a block element. And you forgot to end it, too.

Comment: Yeah! But my div refers strictly to the style of the button. I can't put the text inside that. I have another div for the style of the text before the button but i didn't included in the syntax here.

Comment: So is it working now or not? If not, add it to your question and describe it little more. Then we can try to find another solution and maybe get upvote instead of downvote. You can add screenshoots, too.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

I think you want the lyrics to be inline .

```css
.lyrics {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.lyrics a {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.lyrics a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: #f0d0b5;
}

lyric-align {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
 .lyrics {
   display:inline; 
}
 .song-title {
   display:inline; 
}
```

```html
<p class="song-title">Song Title </p><a class="lyrics" href="#">Lyrics</a></div>
```

If you want a button instead of the link, view [this link.](https://codepen.io/Retrospicer/pen/JjbvRmO)